# Run QT app in QNX from non-root user

Tags: qt, qnx

I would like to run GUI application developed with QT 4.8.5 on QNX 6.5 x86 target from non root user. There is no problem to start app from root user. But then I try to run it from non root user I get this:

```
    $ ./test_app -qws
    QQnxScreen: gf_dev_attach() failed with error code 3
    qnx: driver cannot connect
    Abort (core dumped)
```

In .profile of this user I have:

```
    QWS_KEYBOARD=qnx
    QWS_MOUSE_PROTO=qnx
    QWS_DISPLAY=qnx
    export QWS_KEYBOARD QWS_MOUSE_PROTO QWS_DISPLAY
    export QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/opt/qt485/x86/plugins/
    export QML_IMPORT_PATH=/opt/qt485/x86/imports/
    export PATH=$PATH:/opt/qt485/bin/
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/qt485/x86/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Everything works flawlessly from root with the same setting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include non root user in the display group, perhaps you will be lucky and the video driver will not need I/O privileges. This opportunity is described in the description on io-display (http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/topic/com.qnx.doc.neutrino_utilities/i/io-display.html).

If it did not work, run application as root and set user ID's to non root user after creation of QApplication:

```
#include <unistd.h>         // for setgid and setuid
#include <grp.h>            // for getgrnam
#include <pwd.h>            // for getpwnam
#include <qapplication.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    const struct group* g = getgrnam("user");
    const struct passwd* pw = getpwnam("user");

    QApplication a( argc, argv );

    setgid(g ? g->gr_gid : 0);
    setuid(pw ? pw->pw_uid : 0);
    return a.exec();
}
```